# SharePoint 2016 send email error, certificate validation errors

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, outgoing-mail

I'm facing an issue when trying to send emails from SharePoint, I get one of the error messages below:

```
An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:
  Subject Name: CN=mailservername
  Issuer Name: CN=mailservername
  Thumbprint: 645B2D4B72573478DBD162F39AAE0260B25F6582
  Errors: SSL policy errors have been encountered.  Error code '0x6'..
```

```
An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:
  Subject Name: CN=mailservername
  Issuer Name: CN=mailservername
  Thumbprint: 645B2D4B72573478DBD162F39AAE0260B25F6582
  Errors: The root of the certificate chain is not a trusted root authority..
```

I have a single server farm, with SharePoint server 2016

When I configured the outgoing emails with the exchange server as provided by the IT team (mail.organizationname.gov.xx) or the server IP, I get the first error message.

When I configured it with the mail server name as mentioned in the error (either as is, or with domain (FQDM)) I get the second error !

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have received a good answer on a question I posted on sharepoint.stackexchange:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/257970/40065

From which I learned that the actual problem (In my case) was only on PowerShell "SendEmail" method, and SharePoint itself was working fine with emails

P.S: the answer contains a link to a comprehensive Microsoft Technet blog which covers Configuring TLS encryption between SharePoint on-premise and Exchange